# How to read values from text file and pass it as a URL parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, url

I am trying to read values from a text file (stored in a column) and pass them in a URL parameter. The author ID is unique and I want to iterate on the ID values from the text file.

The data type for content is a list and looks like this:

```
['7202106849\n', '7201570041\n', ....]
```

Here is the code I have written thus far (I know its not complete and I need some help with iteration and passing author IDs from content as a URL parameter)

```
with open('collab_id_2008.txt') as f:
content = f.readlines()

url = "https://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/6602198520?view=metrics"
resp = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept':'application/json','X-ELS-APIKey': 'xxxxxxx', 'X-ELS-Insttoken': 'xxxxxxxx'})
print json.dumps(resp.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: What is the `some help` you require?

Comment: Right now, the API can only pull information for a single author ID. I would like to pass the author IDs from content into url parameter so I can get metrics for all the authors in the text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should get you going:

```
import requests
import json


with open('collab_id_2008.txt') as f_input:
    for id in f_input:
        url = "https://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/{}?view=metrics".format(id.strip())
        resp = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept':'application/json','X-ELS-APIKey': 'xxxxxxx', 'X-ELS-Insttoken': 'xxxxxxxx'})
        print json.dumps(resp.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

This reads your input file and substitutes the `id` into your url.

---

To output to a file, it really depends on the formatting you need, here is one example:

```
with open('collab_id_2008.txt') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for id in f_input:
        url = "https://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/{}?view=metrics".format(id.strip())
        resp = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept':'application/json','X-ELS-APIKey': 'xxxxxxx', 'X-ELS-Insttoken': 'xxxxxxxx'})
        print json.dumps(resp.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
        json.dump(resp.json(), f_output)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! This works great. I would like to write the output in a csv or  json file instead of just outputting the results. Any tips?

Comment: Not having your api key's I can't see the output you are getting, but you can write json to a file using `json.dump()`. I have added an example.